# Vkontakte login authorize prompting every time

Tags: php, vk

I am using vkontakte php sdk https://github.com/AndreyGeonya/vkPhpSdk

here is my code for "login with vkontakte"

```
$oauth2Proxy = new Oauth2Proxy(
$vkclient, // client id
$vksecret, // client secret
'https://oauth.vk.com/access_token', // access token url
'https://oauth.vk.com/authorize', // dialog uri
'code', // response type
'http://localhost/PHP%20workspace/Sputnik/vk_connect.php', // redirect url
    'offline,notify','email' // scope
```

);

```
// Try to authorize client
if($oauth2Proxy->authorize() === true)
{
    // Init vk.com SDK
    $vkPhpSdk = new VkPhpSdk();
    $vkPhpSdk->setAccessToken($oauth2Proxy->getAccessToken());
    $vkPhpSdk->setUserId($oauth2Proxy->getUserId());

    // API call - get profile
    $result = $vkPhpSdk->api('getProfiles', array(
            'uids' => $vkPhpSdk->getUserId(),
            'fields' => 'uid, first_name, last_name, nickname, screen_name, photo_big',
    ));
}
```

Problem: Even the user already authorized receives the authorization dialogue.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the vk sdk but it seems as though `$oauth2Proxy->authorize()` is trying to authorize each time rather than merely check authorization status, is it not the right function to call?

Comment: As per the documnetation $oauth2Proxy->authorize() this is the call for the authorize but i am not sure how to check if the user is already authorized

Answer (score 0):

Just add "&revoke=0" to the dialog uri. this way users are forwarded right away, in case they have authorized your app earlier.